# Select the image but I can't get Uri in Compose | Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Jetpack Compose. I want select Image from gallery and I want get Uri of Image.
I am Using rememberLauncherForActivityResult() but Its not working after I selected Image with launcherMedia.launch(input) .

Code:

```
@Composable
fun ImageScreen(navController: NavController) {

Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Column {
        val sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
        val context = LocalContext.current

        val backStack = remember { mutableStateOf<Boolean>(false) }

        val launcherPermission = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                // Permission Accepted: Do something
                println("ExampleScreen PERMISSION GRANTED")

            } else {
                // Permission Denied: Do something
                println("ExampleScreen PERMISSION DENIED")
            }
            backStack.value = true

        }
        LaunchedEffect(backStack.value) {
            navController.popBackStack()
            backStack.value = false
        }

        val selectedImageURI = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

        //its not working after launcherMedia.launch(input) ,why?
        val launcherMedia = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.GetContent())
        { Uri ->
            print("1234")//not worked
            selectedImageURI.value = Uri
        }


        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            val Permission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            val input = "image/*"
            if (sdkVersion < 29) {
                PermisionState(context, Permission) { isGranted ->
                    if (isGranted)//izin varsa
                    {
                        launcherMedia.launch(input)//its work , I can select Image
                    } else//yoksa
                        launcherPermission.launch(Permission)
                }
            } else {
                launcherMedia.launch(input)//its work I can select Image
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I solve ?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need any permissions for `GetContent`. Have you tried just removing all of that code?

Comment: As @ianhanniballake said you don't need permissions for image selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image picker is working and it is returning URI. You don't see a log message because Kotlin's print function prints to the standard output, not to the Android's Logcat. Just replace `print("1234")` with `Log.d("TAG", "1234")`.
Also you don't need to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` when using `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()`

Here is a working example: (it uses Coil, so add `implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.4.0")` as Gradle dependency)

```
@Composable
fun GetContentExample() {
    var imageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        Log.d("TAG", "URI: $uri")
        imageUri = uri
    }
    Column {
        Button(onClick = { launcher.launch("image/*") }) {
            Text(text = "Load Image")
        }
        Image(
            painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(imageUri),
            contentDescription = "My Image"
        )
    }
}
```